# Vue.js can't toggle a font-awesome icon

Tags: javascript, vue.js, font-awesome

I am trying to toggle a font awesome icon based on a boolean value but it seems that the font-awesome icon remains on the screen after it is drawn:

https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/200312/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-SlE991lGASHoBfWbelyBPLsUlwY1GwNDJo3jSJO04KZ33K2bwfV9YBauFfnzvynJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
￼


<div id="app">
  <input v-model="marked" type="checkbox"/>
  <i v-if="marked" class="far fa-check-square"></i>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    marked: false
  }
})
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in font-awesome or vue.js?

Comment: This sometimes remains and sometimes doesn't. Do you also see this behavior?

Comment: By me, once it appears it remains.

Comment: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3058

Comment: I hate when this things happen when I'm teaching it to someone. It messes my mind.

Comment: This other post helped me resolve a very similar issue: [Font Awesome not updating properly with vue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50242913/5326423)

TLDR: Wrap in <span> or some other component and apply the "key" attribute to the wrapper in order tell Vue not to reuse components.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"i" tag comments out after fire turning to svg, use some wrap `<span v-if="marked"><i  class="far fa-check-square"></i></span>`

Comment: That won't help in this case: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/201741/ I switched from the js to the css as mentioned in the above link and that resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks! couldnt figure out why my SVG was not getting removed from the DOM

Answer (score 17):

I ran into this issue recently when using Vue.js 2.5.x with FontAwesome 5.5.x — the icon classes were not being updated as expected.

*After switching from the FontAwesome Web Fonts + CSS implementation to SVG + JS*, the following code no longer worked:

```
<i :class="[sortByFirstNameAsc ? 'fa-chevron-up' : 'fa-chevron-down', 'fa']"></i>
```

What would happen is that FontAwesome JavaScript would fire and wrap the `<i>` tag and replace it with an SVG element, as in the following simplified example:

```
<span data-v-2614dbd6="">
  <svg data-v-2614dbd6="" class="svg-inline--fa fa-caret-up" ...">
    ...
  </svg>
  
  <!-- <i data-v-2614dbd6="" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i> -->
</span>
```

Unfortunately, the active class was being toggled on the inner, hidden `<i>` tag and not the outer, visible SVG element.

The workaround that restored the [dynamic active class toggling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes) was to wrap the FontAwesome icons in a span and use the [`v-show` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show), as illustrated in the following code snippet:

```
<span v-show="sortByFirstNameAsc"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></span>
<span v-show="sortByFirstNameDesc"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
```

---

The FontAwesome documentation [now recommends](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/vuejs) using their Vue component to avoid conflicts in the DOM:

> **Compatibility Heads Up!**
> If you are using Vue you need the [vue-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome) package or Web Fonts with CSS.

The SVG core package is helpful and recommended in the following cases:

- to subset a large number of icons into only the icons that you are using
- as base libraries for larger integrations with tools like React, Angular, Vue, or Ember (in fact our own components use these packages)
- as CommonJS/ES6 Modules bundling tool like Webpack, Rollup, or Parcel
- as UMD-style loader library like RequireJS
- directly on the server with CommonJS (see our Server Side Rendering docs

Comment: Perfect! Works for me.  Use v-show instead v-if for change fontawesome icons.
Thank you.

Comment: This solution does not work when trying to dynamically change the icon shown.  [This other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242913/font-awesome-not-updating-properly-with-vue)'s selected answer provides a solution that can be used in more situations.  TLDR:  Wrap your icon and apply a key to the wrapper.  For example: <span :key="myIconClass" ><i :class="myIconClass"></i></span>.

Comment: @Efonzie adding a `:key` to the containing element did it for me. Worked perfectly, thank you. Definitely owe you a beer my friend!

Answer (score 5):

### **This answer applies to using Font Awesome with SVG.**

For some reason, you need to wrap the `i` tag twice. For example, instead of this:

```
<div v-if="condition">
  <i class="fal fa-caret-left"></i>
</div>
<div v-else>
  <i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i>
</div>
```

do this:

```
<template v-if="condition">
  <div>
    <i class="fal fa-caret-left"></i>
  </div>
</template>
<template v-else>
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i>
  </div>
</template>
```

Not entirely sure why you need to wrap it twice since I'd think you decouple the `i` tag enough by wrapping it once, but it worked for me this way so there's apparently something else going on.

Also, keep in mind that the inner `div` can't be replaced with `template` for obvious reasons (template tags do not get rendered).

Answer (score 4):

The Font Awesome library you used doesn't know about Vue. It takes the `<i>` that you wrote and turns it into an `<svg>`, and at that point, it's been stolen from Vue. Vue no longer controls it. The [answer that Dialog gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49343449/135101) was a good one: wrap it with a `<span>`. But then you pointed out another scenario it doesn't work for.

To solve your scenario where wrapping with a `<span>` still doesn't work, use `key="fa-sort-up"`. This will force Vue to re-render the wrapper, at which point Font Awesome will update the icon. Here's the [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0pxbq13/) for your example:

```js
<span key="fa-sort-up" v-if="sort && descending"><i class="fas fa-sort-up"></i></span>
<span key="fa-sort-down" v-else-if="sort"><i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i></span>
<span key="fa-sort" v-else><i class="fas fa-sort"></i></span>
```

You can use anything you want for the key, as long as it's unique.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle a checkbox in vue with FontAwesome

```
<style>
  .fa-check-square::before {
    color: green; 
  }
</style>

<script>
  Vue.component('some',
    {
      data: 
        function() {
          return{
            isclick: false
          }
        },
      methods: {
        isClicked: function() {
          this.isclick = !this.isclick;
        }
      },
      template: '<div id="test" v-on:click="isClicked">' +
        '<i v-if="isclick" class="fa fa-check-square" style="font-size: 40px;"></i>' +
        '<i v-if="!isclick" class="far fa-square" style="font-size: 40px;"></i>' +
        '</div>'
    });

</script>

<div id="componentsDemo">
  <some></some>
  <some></some>
  <some></some>
  <some></some>
</div>

<script>
  new Vue({ el: '#componentsDemo' });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by creating a template for each icon, then loading either template conditionally based on a boolean.

Here's my main template:

```html
 <div v-if="minimised">

                        <maximise-icon>
                            
                        </maximise-icon>

                    </div>

                    <div v-if="!minimised">

                        <minimise-icon>
                        
                        </minimise-icon>
                     </div>
```

Then just create the icons like so:

```js
FontAwesomeConfig = { autoReplaceSvg: 'nest' }//important addition!

Vue.component('minimise-icon', {

    template:
    `
        <i class="fas fa-minus "></i>

    `

})


Vue.component('maximise-icon', {

    template:
    `
        <i class="fas fa-plus "></i>

    `

})
```

If there's a more elegant way I'm all ears!