# Vue v-if not working even though condition is met (Font Awesome icon not updating)

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, vue-cli

In VueJS I have a table with columns that can be sorted. Only one column can be sorted at a time.

Before sorting, the button is `fa-sort`. After sorting, the button changes to `fa-arrow-up` and then to `fa-arrow-down` if clicked again.

When I was prototyping my project importing the Vue library script, the v-if worked. But after migrating to Vue CLI, this does not work.

Now if I click the sort button, the sorting is applied but the button icon does not change. However, if I go in my Vue tools and changed the `colBeingSorted` value in there, the button icon *does* update.

I have tried many things: I moved the condition (or a variation of it) into a computed, then into a method. I've also printed and console.logged the data to confirm it is what I expect. In all cases, I can confirm the condition is met but for some reason the icon does not update.

Any ideas? Suggestions?

I have reduced the code sample considerably so it doesn't show the sort function, only the button icon formatting. `sortedAscending` is updated in the sort function which is working correctly:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-for="(column, prop) in header" :key="prop">
        <button-component
          v-if="colBeingSorted != prop"
          :icon="'fas fa-sort'"
          @click="colBeingSorted = prop"
        >
        <button-component
          v-else-if="colBeingSorted == prop && sortedAscending == true"
          :icon="'fas fa-arrow-up'"
        >
        <button-component
          v-else-if="colBeingSorted == prop && sortedAscending == false"
          :icon="'fas fa-arrow-down'"
        >
        {{ column }}
...
```

```js
data() {
    return {
      colBeingSorted: -1,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Maylor I implemented your change and although it didn't fix the problem on its own, it did make my code cleaner and easier to debug.

After more investigation I found that the problem was not in my Vue code but related to Font Awesome. Under the hood, my `button-component` uses Font Awesome, which was not re-rendering the icon even though the value had changed.

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242913/font-awesome-not-updating-properly-with-vue), I removed `fontawesome/js/all.js` and now am only using `fontawesome/css/all.css`. This solved the problem.

Comment: Sounds good to me - good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why this is happening from the code snippet, but I often find things work just nicer if you try and keep the same component and change the props, rather than having if-else's with different instances of the same component. One way you could do this is by having just 1 button component:

```
<button-component
  :icon="getIcon(prop)"
  @click="handleClick(prop)"
/>
```

methods something like this

```
getIcon(prop) {
  if (this.colBeingSorted != prop) return 'fas fa-sort';
  if (sortedAscending) return 'fas fa-arrow-up';
  return 'fas fa-arrow-down';
},
handleClick(prop) {
  if (this.colBeingSorted == prop) {
    this.sortedAscending = !this.sortedAscending;
  } else {
    this.colBeingSorted = prop;
    this.sortedAscending = true;
  }
}
```

As an aside I don't think I've seen 'prop' being used here when just referring to the index of an item in an array. Especially confusing in Vue when prop has a very particular meaning! I'd just use columnIndex in this case.